# One date picker for all combo boxes in an Excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker

What I'd like to accomplish:

1. Have separate comboboxes on a userform, such that when the individual drop down button is clicked, load a global userform with the calendar control on it. Since I will have multiple combo boxes, it wouldn't be feasible to keep adding new separate userforms with calendars controls on it. Instead, just to have one main userform with a calendar control that does all of the work for all my combo boxes.
2. When a date is selected from the global date picker calendar control, to insert the selected date into the combo box that was clicked.

I've found pieces but I can't make sense of them since I am new to this.

Comment: So you want to use a single calendar as input and drop down boxes as output, is that correct?

Comment: Have you thought of using a native Microsoft date picker control instead of combo boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about this, I can think of one solution.
Add a Label.

When clicking the combobox, the label will have the combobox name, then from there, when you click a date in the calendar control, it will send the date to the combobox name in the label.
[image]

I just grabbed whatever calendar control that was available in the toolbox, yours may be different.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Me.Label1 = Me.ComboBox1.Name
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_DropButtonClick()
    Me.Label1 = Me.ComboBox2.Name
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox3_DropButtonClick()
    Me.Label1 = Me.ComboBox3.Name
End Sub

Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
    s = Me.Label1.Caption
    Me.Controls(s) = Me.MonthView1.Value
End Sub
```

As pointed out by @MathieuGuindon, when clicking the combobox you can assign the tag to the Calendar control, then you would not have to place the label approach.

Thanks Mathieu...

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Me.MonthView1.Tag = Me.ComboBox1.Name
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_DropButtonClick()
    Me.MonthView1.Tag = Me.ComboBox2.Name
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox3_DropButtonClick()
    Me.MonthView1.Tag = Me.ComboBox3.Name
End Sub

Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
    s = Me.MonthView1.Tag
    Me.Controls(s) = Me.MonthView1
End Sub
```

Comment: Or you could just use the `MonthView` control's `Tag` property.

Comment: For example? @MathieuGuindon

Comment: `Me.MonthView1.Tag = Me.ComboBox1.Name`, then `s = Me.MonthView1.Tag`